# How do I use the "web browser app"?

Tags: browser, webapps

There is an extra browser in ubuntu 14.04 other than Firefox, "the browser app" which looks like a mobile browser.

It also has an earth shaped icon.It is not like a traditional browser. I know we can open new tab in it by going to activity icon, but I dont know how to close a tab, I want to know if it is possible to do private browsing in that browser,I cant select text, I cant do direct download of anything. Some help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Closing a tab: {activity=>long press on the opened tabs}Do a long press on the opened tabs(its a long left click) then red coloured into marks will apppear, this way you can close it, if you don' t wanna close it, again do a long press on the open tabs.

Private browsing: I haven't figured that out (or) it does not seem to exist on this one.

Still direct download is not working & I cant select text.(how ever I have filed a bug)

Comment: Why are two packages included? Firefox is clearly the [much] better app and also meets the free app criteria.

Comment: I guess that is Ubuntu's choice to include their half baked apps into the distro.

Answer (score 5):

The browser app was being developed since starting of 2013. From Ubuntu 14.04, it will be available as system app.

You may find more information about this app from launchpad: https://launchpad.net/webbrowser-app

Try `Alt+F4` to close the browser.

Comment: it asked how to close the tabs, not the window itself.